# Changing a value in a yaml file using Python

Tags: python, yaml, pyyaml

I have a `.yaml` file I want to update with Python code. Let's say it looks something like that:

```
  state: 'present'
```

I'd like to have a code that changes the state and saves the file. I'm trying with something like this and fail:

```
def set_state(state):
    with open("file_to_edit.yaml", 'rw') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f)
    doc['state'] = state
    yaml.dump(f)
```

I am using the 'yaml' package for Python.

Comment: Do you get an error of some kind?

Comment: Nope, it just didn't change anything

Comment: It just doesn't seem to be writing to the file for some reason

Comment: So (just to be clear) if you print the state after your change, you see it applied – but it doesn't save back to the file? Unsure of my Python skills: isn't it a problem that your line `yaml.dump(f)` accesses `f` outside the scope of the `with .. as f:`?

Comment: Your comment made sense so I tried it out but still this doesn't look like working.. The file is still not being written

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The problem is that `yaml.dump(doc)` doesn't actually write to a file. Instead, [it returns the modified YAML as a string](http://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#DumpingYAML) unless you pass the file descriptor as argument as well, which allows you to write directly to the file.

The following should work:

```
def set_state(state):
    with open('file_to_edit.yaml') as f:
        doc = yaml.load(f)

    doc['state'] = state

    with open('file_to_edit.yaml', 'w') as f:
        yaml.dump(doc, f)
```

Comment: What do you call a YAML structure? `dump()` returns a string (which contains a YAML document) unless you specify a `stream` parameter (which you should). Writing that returned string to file is an inefficient (wrt time and memory usage) way of using `yaml.dump()` and bad advice.

Comment: Can't we just replace the corresponding key in the file instead of reading and writing complete file itself?

Answer (score 9):

Before anything else: **never use `yaml.load()` if you don't have to**, as it is in principle unsafe to do so. For this kind of simple structure (without tags) you should use `yaml.safe_load()` (and the corresponding `safe_dump()` that will complain if your data cannot be safe_loaded after dumping).

`yaml.dump()` has the following signature:

```
def dump(documents, stream=None, Dumper=Dumper,
         default_style=None, default_flow_style=None,
         canonical=None, indent=None, width=None,
         allow_unicode=None, line_break=None,
         encoding='utf-8', explicit_start=None, explicit_end=None,
         version=None, tags=None)
```

Of this only the first one needs to be given, that should be your `doc` variable. If you don't specify a stream, then `dump()` writes data structure to an in memory file-object (like StringIO) and after writing returns the value as string.

So although you could do:

```
with open("file_to_edit.yaml", 'w') as f:
    f.write(yaml.safe_dump(doc))
```

this is inefficient and shows little understanding of how `yaml.safe_dump()` works.

If you want to open the file for reading and writing you have to make sure you both reset the index in the file **and** truncate its content. This is usually not worth the effort so it is safer to re-open the file for writing:

```
def set_state(state):
    file_name = "file_to_edit.yaml"
    with open(file_name) as f:
        doc = yaml.safe_load(f)
    doc['state'] = state
    with open(file_name, 'w') as f:
        yaml.safe_dump(doc, f, default_flow_style=False)
```

(of course you make the filename a variable when you want to make sure you overwrite the original, so you cannot mistype it).

If you don't specify `default_flow_style=False`, your output will look like:

```
{state: deleted}
```

The output will not include the superfluous quotes around `present` in your input. You can specify `default_style="'"` as well, but this will also put quotes around `state`.
If losing the quotes is a problem and you really want the output to look like the input, you should be using `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer I am the author of that package), which can preserve the quotes on individual strings, handles YAML 1.2 (instead of YAML 1.1) and also preserves comments in your file.

Comment: thanks . but that _safe_dump funtion does not support saving Decimal

Comment: What is holding you back to add a repreesenter for Decimal to the dumper?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you didn't indent properly, since your function in its current state seems not to do anything. Python **does** care about indentation.

Try this:

```py
    def set_state(state):
        with open("file_to_edit.yaml", 'rw') as f:
            doc = yaml.load(f)
        doc['state'] = state
        yaml.dump(f)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following (it creates a new file to store the result):

```
with open("output_file", 'a') as out:
    with open("input_file", 'r') as f:
        for line in f:
            line = re.sub(r"state: present", "state: installed", line)
            out.write(line)
```