# How do I edit a YAML file through python using ruamel.yaml and not pyyaml?

Tags: python, yaml

I found similar questions here on StackOverflow, but when I tried to implement the code [[Anthons's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29518833/editing-yaml-file-by-python)] to suit my situation, I noticed that it does not actually edit the YAML file. Also, I need to use [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), not PyYAML. Many of the answers I've reviewed use PyYAML.

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml  

yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()
# yaml.preserve_quotes = True

with open('elastic.yml') as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)

data['cluster.name'] = 'BLABLABLABLABLA'
data['node.name'] = 'HEHEHEHEHEHEHE'

yaml.dump(data, sys.stdout)
```

This code outputs the file with the correct edits, however, when I actually go into the file (`elastic.yml`), the original documentation is unchanged.

This is my first experience with [ruamel.yaml](https://yaml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and I would rather stick with this because I've noticed PyYAML does not keep comments.

The YAML file after I run the python code:

```
cluster.name: my-application

# Use a descriptive name for the node:
node.name: HappyNode
```

The output to the console after I run the python code:

```
cluster.name: BLABLABLABLABLA

# Use a descriptive name for the node:
node.name: HEHEHEHEHEHEHE
```

I've tried adding this to the bottom of the code to assure it write to the file, as described here:[[Matheus Portela's response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40762382/changing-a-value-in-a-yaml-file-using-python)] but I get no luck:

```
with open('elastic.yml', 'w') as f:
    yaml.dump(data, f)
```

I get the following error:

```
data['cluster.name'] = 'BLABLABLABLABLA'
TypeError: 'NoneType' object does not support item assignment
```

Comment: Your code (including writing the file) works for me. So I guess this is not your real code.

Comment: Well you guess wrong

Comment: I can reproduce your error with: `foo = None; foo["foo"] = 23`. check if data contains what you think it does. as I said the code you posted works for me

Comment: Ok, I shall look into that. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Assuming that the (unchanged) `elastic.yml` is your input, you can run:

```
import ruamel.yaml  

file_name = 'elastic.yml'
yaml = ruamel.yaml.YAML()

with open(file_name) as fp:
    data = yaml.load(fp)

data['cluster.name'] = 'BLABLABLABLABLA'
data['node.name'] = 'HEHEHEHEHEHEHE'

with open(file_name, 'w') as fp:
    yaml.dump(data, fp)

# display file
with open(file_name) as fp:
    print(fp.read(), end='')
```

to get the following output:

```
cluster.name: BLABLABLABLABLA

# Use a descriptive name for the node:
node.name: HEHEHEHEHEHEHE
```

Since the program displays the content of the file, you can be sure it has changed